# Save hive table from spark in hive 2.1.1

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, hive, apache-spark-sql, configuration-files

Iam using Spark 2.2 with scala, hive 2.1.1 and zeppelin on ubuntu 16.04.
In addition, i copied hive-site.xml to spark/conf/ and mysql-connector-java.jar from hive/libs to spark/jars

I want to save a dataframe as hivetable and iam doing this with:

```
val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
df.registerTempTable("myTempTable")
hc.sql("create table store_sales as select * from myTempTable")
```

after in my notebook, i run this.

```
%hive
show tables;
```

And i can see that my new hivetable store_sales was created, but i cant run hive after of this.

This is my hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
                <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?useSSL=false</value>
                <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
                <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
                <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
                <value>hive</value>
                <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
                <value>hive</value>
                <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
                <value>spark</value>
                <description>set hive on spark</description>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

when i running hive

```
root@alex-bi:/usr/local/hive/bin# hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Hive Schema version 2.1.0 does not match metastore's schema version 1.2.0 Metastore is not upgraded or corrupt)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7768)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:565)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:626)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 28 more
```

I think that this is problem of jars located in spark/jars

```
hive-beeline-1.2.1.spark2.jar
hive-cli-1.2.1.spark2.jar
hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar
hive-jdbc-1.2.1.spark2.jar
hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar
```

because spark save by default in hiveTable version 1.2.1, but i dont know how to configure spark to save hivetable version 2.1.1 that this is my local hive installation. I changed these jars for those of hive/lib version 2.1.1 but it did not work and I dont know what else to try, and google does not help.

I need this because i want to save spark dataframe in hivetable to after read this table with kylin, and maybe it's not the right way to do it and there is another way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On a real Hadoop cluster, you would have set up a Metastore service, so that neither Hive nor Spark would have accessed the database directly. Here you are running an "embedded" Metastore in Spark _and_ in Hive; you ran Spark first, so that it initialized the DB with its preferred version (1.2), then Hive failed. Maybe if you had run Hive first it would have worked. Or maybe not.

Comment: Use Spark on Yarn with Cloudera. You only have to select an option in Cloudera Manager and your Spark works seamlessly with Hive. Can't get easier than that.

Comment: I have installed Hive 2.1.1. with mysql engine as a metastore service, to which also other applications are connected to consult the data, for example kylin. And this works correctly. My final goal is not to start hive exactly, it is to save from spark data in hive so that I can consult that data with other applications.
If I create a table from hive or mysql, a schema version 2.1.1 is created correctly, But when I try to pass a spark dataframe to hive, spark did it in schema version 1.2.1 then it is when crashed all.ç
iam looking a way to introduce the dataframe worked in spark in hive.

Comment: I got hive to run in two different ways, adding configuration to hive-site.xml so that it does not check the schemaVersion, and the other way is updating the schema (for that I had to modify the script because having a table in the version 2.1, trying to update tried to create tables that already existed, giving error by primary key or existing tables)

But I still see weak spark at this point, I should be able to create a hive table from spark with the schemaVersion that I want

Comment: @AlejandroReina what was the solution to save tables to hive from spark in this scenario? did you replace the jars?

Comment: you have the answer in the comment above (Alejandro Reina Dec 10 '17 at 19:07   )